# Xamarin Forms XAML databinding from android-project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I want to use Xaml if possible instead of axml. (It's a cross platform proj.)
For example I want to list the installed apps in android.
I can query them, but what to do with it to show? (And as a sidenote, where to query, just after the OnCreate's LoadApplication call?)

In the android project I have MainActivity, OnCreate() inside, and in that LoadApplication() called... which is confusing for me as in the examples I found SetContentView() a lot of time.
But anyway, how to show things which come from android-specific code? (Of course net is full with easy neutral xamarin forms like login or showing data loaded from the net.)
It might be a bit complicated (as it's a list, I may need an adapter, I don't know yet as I try using Xaml), but I don't even know how to show e.g. just the first app's name on a Label.

Sorry I'm new to Xamarin, I just try to use C# with Xaml for android development. I hope it's possible.

Comment: if it's a cross platform project, you want to write your XAML UI in the your shared Forms project, and use DependencyService to call the platform specific code.

Comment: @Jason Thank you very much, that's the solution to my problems. If you write it as an answer, I will be able to accept it.